# Is a static variable in an apk available to a background service?

Tags: android, android-service, static-variables

I am using a helper class for a couple of static flags for my app.

Would a background service started from my app have access to those flags in case my app is not running?

EDIT: When I am testing it, it seems to work, I would just like to know if it is a recommended  thing to do. (Or should I use a singleton or the strings.xml file? Do these persist?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK yes it would be available. If you have few constants that remain same overtime, you can create a `Constants` class and put your static values there.

```
public class Constants {
    public final static String MY_CONSTANT = "VALUE";
    // ... all the other constants 
}
```

You can access these constants from any class within the app and for using it from your `service` just do `Constants.MY_CONSTANT`.

**Edit:**

> When I am testing it, it seems to work, I would just like to know if it is a recommended thing to do. (Or should I use a singleton or the strings.xml file? Do these persist?)

Yes its a recommended thing to do. 
Check answers here [Android intent Filters: better as constant or in String.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317132/android-intent-filters-better-as-constant-or-in-string-xml)

Comment: Yeap, that's what I am doing, so basically this string will "live" in the same process as the Service and thus be available, even though my app is not running, right?